# html-loader not recognising img tags in html

Tags: webpack

I am trying to bundle an application using webpack and I'm using html-loader with file-loader to bundle images into an 'imgs' folder within the dist directory (which is not happening).

I have tried importing an image into one of the javascript entry points and this works fine, file-loader recognized the image and bundles it correctly.

File system:

[image: Screenshot with link to file system image]

Build script and dependencies from package.json:

```js
 "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js"
```

```js
 "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "file-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "glob": "^7.1.5",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.2"
  }
```

webpack.prod.js:

```js
const path = require("path");
const common = require("./webpack.common");
const merge = require("webpack-merge");

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: "production",
  output: {
    filename: "main.[contentHash].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
  },
});
```

webpack.common.js:

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const glob = require("glob");

module.exports = {
  entry: glob.sync("./src/scripts/*.js"),
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/template.html"
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: {
          loader: "html-loader",
          options: {
            attrs: [":data-src"]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            name: "[name].[hash].[ext]",
            outputPath: "imgs/"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

from template.html:

```html
            <div class="home-screen">
              <div class="app-container">
                <div>
                  <img width="54" height="54" data-name="calculator" src="/src/assets/calc-icon.png"></img>
                  <p>Calculator</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <img width="54" height="54" data-name="video-player" src="/src/assets/video-player-icon.png"></img>
                  <p>Video Player</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <img width="54" height="54" data-name="temp-converter"
                    src="/src/assets/temp-converter-icon.png"></img>
                  <p>Temperature Converter</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <img width="54" height="54" data-name="color-game" src="/src/assets/color-game-icon.png"></img>
                  <p>Color Game</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <img id="camera-icon" width="54" height="54" data-name="camera-app"
                    src="/src/assets/camera-icon.png"></img>
                  <p>Camera</p>
                </div>
```

So when I run `npm run build` I expect the dist directory to include a index.html, main.js and an `imgs` folder containing my images but the `imgs` folder simply doesn't show up with no error messages to indicate why. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing "/src/assets/*" for your images from the template.html file that is already inside your src folder. So when comparing with your base directory it is looking for /src/src/assets/* which doesn't exist.

Change the img src attributes inside src/template.html to use "./assets" instead of "/src/assets" to solve the problem.

Comment: That was exactly it! Thank you so much!